# Vim auto commands: writing a read-only file?

Tags: vim, perforce

I'm using Perforce with Vim on Windows.
I currently have an auto command set up to open a read-only file for edit when changing it:

```
au FileChangedRO * !p4 edit <afile>
```

Is there any way to set up a similar auto command to execute `p4 edit` when attempting to *write*  a read-only file rather than edit it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an auto command attached to the  *BufWritePre* event, that checks whether the file is read only or not and executes *p4 edit* on demand.  Something like:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :if &readonly | !p4 edit %
```

Comment: This is also very helpful if you use Vim with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the perforce plugin a shot. I find it very useful.