# How do I automatically open a file for edit in perforce, if writing a read-only file in vim?

Tags: perforce, vim

This is very similar to:

[Vim auto commands: writing a read-only file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681058/vim-auto-commands-writing-a-read-only-file)

Except that in addition to the solution presented there, I want vim to only ask for confirmation if the file is *still* read-only.

In other words, if I do :w, I do not want vim to say that the file is read-only. It should automatically open the file for edit using perforce, and only if the file is *still* read-only should it then ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also be interested in the [Perforce plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=167) for vim.

Comment: This is still the best answer I've seen here, so I've accepted it - in practice, however, I'm just living with the unneccessary confirmation dialogue and continuing with normal mode mappings, in combination with having vim reload the file if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
autocmd! bufreadpost * :if &readonly && confirm('File is read only. Open for edit?', "&Yes\n&No", 1) == 1 | setlocal noreadonly writeany
```

Comment: This must be in addition to the BufReadPre handler from the other answer, I assume?

Comment: OP wants to try checking out with Perforce (p4) first.